# Call custom function of controller from ajax symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, symfony-sonata

I've created the forms using Sonata Admin Bundle. Then I've created my own Controller (TestController) and override the CRUD controller,

I've added a new function in the TestController,

```
namespace IFI2\MainProjectBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;


//use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function getProductPricesAction() {

         file_put_contents("/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/IFI2 CMS/Logs.txt","HELO",FILE_APPEND);

          return new Response(json_encode($response)); 

    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to access this function via my javascript Code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function test1() {

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            //dataType: "json",
            url: '{{ path('main_project.admin.test')}}',
            success: function(successMsg) {
                alert("successMsg");

            },
            error: function(errorMsg) {
                alert("errorMsg");

            }
        });
     }

</script>
```

Here's my routing.yml,

```
main_project.admin.test:
  pattern:  /getProductPrices/
  defaults: { _controller: IFI2MainProjectBundle:Test:getProductPrices}
```

I've already had services.yml entry for this entity,

```
main_project.admin.cobrand:
    class: MainProjectBundle\Admin\TestAdmin
    arguments: [~, MainProjectBundle\Entity\Test, "MainProjectBundle:Test"]
    tags:
        - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Test}
    calls:
        - [setTemplate, [edit, MainProjectBundle:Test:edit.html.twig]]
```

I'm getting the following error in my response,

There is no `_sonata_admin` defined for the controller `MainProjectBundle\Controller\TestController` and the current route `main_project.admin.test`

Kindly, help me how to embed it ?

Thanks,
Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add new route in your Admin method configureRoutes

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    parent::configureRoutes($collection);
    $collection->add('get_product_prices');
}
```

Remove your route main_project.admin.test

New route has $baseRouteName from your admin as prefix and has name:

```
base_route_name_get_product_prices
```

using

```
{{ path('base_route_name_get_product_prices') }}
//or with admin
{{ admin.generateUrl('get_product_prices') }}
```

Comment: How to add route parameter in the collection ? I want to add the id as parameter

Comment: Its the same in both variants:
path('base_route_name_get_product_prices',{'id': 1})
admin.generateUrl('get_product_prices',{'id': 1})

Answer (score 0):

In routing.yml add the following:

```html
main_project.admin.test:
  pattern:  /getProductPrices/
  defaults: { _controller: IFI2MainProjectBundle:Test:getProductPrices,"_sonata_admin": "main_project.admin.cobrand" }
```